# Historic events

Tags: word-meaning

Is it okay to say 'historic events'?

It feels kind of double, because both meanings have something to do with the word 'important'

historic means: famous or important in history, or potentially so.

And event means: a thing that happens or takes place, especially one of importance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, "historic event(s)" is a perfectly idiomatic phrase. Just be careful of the difference between "historic events" and "**historical** events."

A **historic event** is a notable event that is well-known and had a particularly large impact.

**Historical events** are simply those which are recorded in history. They are not necessarily well known or momentous.